# Is $V_\text{RMS}$ an unfortunate abuse of operator?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, electric-current, education

My book introduces RMS voltage as typical in a discussion regarding AC circuits, however I now understand this as a tool of statistical mechanics.

It would seem as though oscillation is not a great place to need to bring in statistical techniques, since it is generally well-determined motion from well-determined dynamics, and something about this practice leaves a sour taste in my mouth, suddenly feeling inelegant and out-of-place.

Are there consequences for this type of abuse that a novice physicist should be introduced to, or is this just a song for all the aspiring electrical engineers in the crowd?

Comment: I don't really understand the question.  The RMS voltage is a perfectly fine quantity to report when discussing oscillating signals. What abuse do you imagine is occurring?

Comment: So far as I understand it, those operators are for use on probability densities, such as Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution. I understand too that they'll be used for understanding power dissipation, but there doesn't seem a natural need to invoke statistics.

Comment: I think you're reading too far into this. If you have a sinusoidally-varying signal, its average over one cycle is zero. There are a number of ways of quantifying the signal's strength - one would be to specify the peak amplitude of the oscillation, while another would be to square the signal, average that, and then take the square root of the result. The latter is useful in many contexts - as you say, it is the relevant quantity for power dissipation.

Comment: I'm beginning to suspect you're right, the principles I wonder about are perfectly well-elucidated somewhere, and that mean is a "fantastic use" of an operator, rather than an abuse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an ohmic circuit, the power is

$$
P= VI=I^2R=\frac{V^2}{R}
$$

A direct-current voltmeter should just report the voltage. But to measure an alternating voltage, you have to have a different detection circuit, with some sort of rectifier.  In an old-fashioned galvanometer with a physical needle, the needle can only “bounce” with some hertz-ish frequency, and so you have to choose a meter calibration for where the needle will end up in the high-frequency, invisible-bouncing limit.

If you calibrate your meter to report the root of the mean of the square $V_\text{rms}=\sqrt{\left<V^2\right>}$, you have the property that $(V_\text{rms})^2$ is the mean value of $V^2$, and so squaring the number on the meter gives you the correct number for computing the average power.  It’s in the textbooks, and in your lab hardware, because it is useful and convenient.

Note that the “mean” in this case is *not* based on a statistically random sample of any population.  An analog meter is “sampling” continuously; a digital meter includes some analog smoothing electronics and then samples at some approximately-constant frequency.

Beware that the “rms” calibration for a voltmeter (of any design, analog or digital) is typically calibrated for sinusoidal waves with a single frequency, within a frequency range which is usually documented on the housing of the meter. For a signal with a different shape, like a triangle wave or a square wave or a digital pulse train (which is usually a square wave with a DC offset and some non-50% duty factor), exactly how the meter reading will compare to the amplitude can be hard to predict.

Comment: I think these are the sort of assertions I'm looking for, and that the generality provided by permitting this kind of weighted-sum is what enables Fourier analysis, as a type of weighted sum.

Comment: Yes, but do your Fourier analysis carefully. Consider that a digital pulse train with 10% duty factor has the same Fourier power spectrum as a pulse train with 90% duty factor, apart from some phase differences to flip the sign of the signal relative to its DC Fourier component. But the 90% “on” square wave will pull more power than its 90% “off” cousin. Don’t make my mistake of overzealously zeroing out the cross terms.

Answer (score 6):

I think you are overthinking this. In this context, the "mean" in root mean square just refers to the time average of a function over one period,
\begin{align}
\text{mean}(f) = \frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^{T} f(t)\,dt
\end{align}
not the mean of a random variable. Sure, you could interpret this in terms of random variables if you wanted to, but it's completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

This answer doesn't attempt to explain the meaning of 'rms', as I assume that the questioner already knows the meaning.

The rms voltage could indeed be called a statistical idea, but it is a very simple one. You are uneasy applying it to "generally well-determined motion from well-determined dynamics", by which I assume you mean a sinusoidally varying voltage. But you can equally well apply it to an irregularly varying voltage, and it still serves the same purpose, namely ...

The rms voltage is equal to the steady voltage that gives the same power dissipation in a given resistance as the actual varying voltage. It is surely interesting to physicists as well as electrical engineers to know that a sinusoidal voltage of peak value 12.0 V has the same heating power as a steady voltage of 8.5 V (the rms value).

Comment: So, it's your contention that the need arises naturally from "adding up" of "instantaneous power dissipation" -- which happens to be spelled like RMS?

Comment: Your comment is too cryptic for me to understand. Maybe someone else will understand it, or you might consider expanding the comment.

Comment: Average was introduced as a technique of measurement in kinematics, and Newton's laws derived from the observation that up to instantaneous measurements, no deviation has been observed -- the base need arose from connecting discrete experimental measurements to a law. I suppose then you would also contend the need arises because of the infeasibility of measuring drift velocity and the effects of subatomic particle collisions accurately across the population, except as macroscopic physical properties?

Comment: I wouldn't contend this; I'm trying, perhaps unsuccessfully, to defend the use of $V_{\text{rms}}$ only when the voltage variation is known, that is in macroscopic terms.